# PHP parse json and insert to database

Tags: php, json

I have a json data.
What i want is to parse it and insert on database.
My fields on Table are: DateTime,Long,Lat

However,i'm stuck with this and dont know how to proceed.
Please help me.
Here is my code:

```
$data = '{"LOC":"860037031396220:[2017-06-17 
13:29:29|14.4364699,121.0126454||2017-06-17 
13:30:02|14.4364783,121.0125981]"}';
$json = (object)json_decode($data,true);
$array =  $json->LOC;
$xp = explode(':',$array,2);
$imei = $xp[0];
$coords =  $xp[1];
$keywords = array('[',']');
$coords = str_replace($keywords,'',$coords);
$coords_xp = explode('||',$coords);
foreach($coords_xp AS $coordsxp){
    echo $coordsxp;
}

Output:
2017-06-17 13:29:29|14.4364699,121.01264542017-06-17 
13:30:02|14.4364783,121.0125981
```

How can i insert these data in a database?

Thanks

Comment: Look at the [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) and/or [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/class.mysqli.php) docs. They have examples for reading and writing to a database.

Comment: If you want `json_decode()` to return an object, leave out the `true` argument, you don't need to use the `(object)` cast.

Comment: You insert the data from a JSON object the same way you insert any other data into the database. Once you've decoded it, it's just a PHP object or array, there's nothing special about it.